# Add your business to Apple maps

Tags: ios6-maps, apple-maps

Any idea on how to add business to Apple Maps? They are very incomplete, and none of my client's business are appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did that for a friend's restaurant. Hope it'll appear quickly on Apple maps app.

You should start with adding the business to yelp.com and places.tomtom.com

There are very good articles on that subject here:

http://tophatrank.com/blog/search-engine-optimization/apple-maps/